# Handle Authorization in GWT application

Tags: java, gwt, servlets, authorization, jaas

I am planing to use JAAS for authorization purpose.

I am using GWT on GUI side and Java on server side.

Please suggest some code to handle authorization using JAAS. Does it has support for GWT?. Is there any way to control disable and enable button using JAAS?

Does any library available to handle authorization for GWT appliation?.

Comment: Check out this, it might be useful for you --
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/google-web-toolkit/GNfiSemD6XY/EhzInUsbgJAJ

Comment: @SCK the link you shared is for authentication purpose only. I am looking for authorization.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK there is no library in `GWT` that handles authorization.

That's also not really straightforward as authorization is mainly handled on the backend and there is wide range of different implementations and patterns (RBAC, etc). 
It's really hard to come up with a generic approach that covers all the use cases. You probably have to roll your own design/systen.

For example we attach `PermissionObjects` (simple Beans) to `DTO`s that are sent to the wire to the client (GWT).
On the client side we check the permissions and disable or enable or display `widgets`(Buttons, Links, etc).

You can of course come up with a more fancy generic solution by extending widgets and incorporating authorization.

Just one thing to remember: **Never trust the client.**

So even when you disable or hide a button that calls a service/function on the backend, make sure to check the permissions again on the backend.

Answer (score 1):

The Spring Security 3.1 provides functionality for user authentication and authorization.

Comment: Check this question, you may find something useful there:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914547/gwt-spring-security-integration-pure-gwt-no-jsp

Answer (score 0):

If you're searchig to go further by controlling what is visible/enabled to the user (authorizations), and how it is displayed. I just created a solution for that. I hope you'll enjoy:

Use the project UiBinderAutho to catch widget creation and adapt them to your needs (connected profile ui, rights, widget handlers). Some explanations here
http://ziedhamdi.github.io/UiBinderAutho/

here are the github projects
https://github.com/ziedHamdi