# GWT spring security login

Tags: spring-security, gxt, gwt-mvp

I´m using GWT and MVP and 2.4 and Spring security for securising  my application .but dont want to use  JSP login page(default page).i want to use my propre page.
this is my securitydemo.xml:

logtest is the name of my project, i use lohtest.html  like default page

and i have a message like this :access denied  in the console
 and in the page message like:GWT module 'logtest' may need to be (re)compiled

please if you have some idea about the problems

```
<!-- HTTP security configurations -->
<http auto-config='true'>

    <intercept-url pattern="/logtest.html" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/resources/favicon.ico" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />




    <form-login login-page="/Logtest.html" />

    <logout logout-success-url="/logtest.html" />

    <session-management invalid-session-url="/logtest.html"

        session-authentication-error-url="/logtest.html"

        session-fixation-protection="newSession">

        <concurrency-control max-sessions="1"
            error-if-maximum-exceeded="false" />
    </session-management>
</http>


<authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="sha" />
        <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource"
            users-by-username-query="
              select username,password, enabled 
              from users where username=?"

            authorities-by-username-query="
              select u.username, ur.authority from users u, user_roles ur 
              where u.user_id = ur.user_id and u.username =?  " />
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [GWT Spring Security Integration (PURE GWT, NO JSP)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914547/gwt-spring-security-integration-pure-gwt-no-jsp)