# AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext

Tags: spring, gwt, spring-security

I have this implementation of a login function on my server following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13914547/gwt-spring-security-integration-pure-gwt-no-jsp) basically:

```
@Transactional
public void login(String userId, String password) {

    LOGGER.debug("Login for " + userId);

    User user = new User(userId, password, true, true, true, true, new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

    Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, password,
            new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>());

    try {
        auth = this.authenticationProvider.authenticate(auth);
    } catch(BadCredentialsException e) {
        LOGGER.debug("Bad credentials ..");
        throw new RuntimeException(e.getMessage());
    }

    LOGGER.debug("User successfully authenticated [userId="+userId+"]");

    SecurityContext sc = new SecurityContextImpl();
    sc.setAuthentication(auth);

    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(sc);       
}
```

This appears to work so far without any troubles. However, if I execute this request right after login

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('ADMIN')")
public void test(String msg) {
    LOGGER.debug("test: " + msg);
}
```

the result is this exception here:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationCredentialsNotFoundException: An Authentication object was not found in the SecurityContext
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.credentialsNotFound(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:378)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:222)
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.aopalliance.MethodSecurityInterceptor.invoke(MethodSecurityInterceptor.java:64)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at com.mz.server.web.service.LoginService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$caf0e62d_2.test(<generated>)
    at com.mz.server.web.servlet.LoginServletImpl.test(LoginServletImpl.java:99)
```

Reading about `SecurityContextHolder.setContext()` it says:

> Associates a new `SecurityContext` with the current thread of execution.

so I guess my problem here is that I don't understand how Spring can recall a user that just logged into my system and now wants to proceed with authenticated request.

And why am I not just getting redirected to `/login`?

---

**Spring** context:

```
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- // BEGIN Spring Security -->

<sec:http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true"/>

<bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
    <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/**" filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<bean id="authenticationListener" class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationListener"/>

<bean id="authenticationProvider" class="com.mz.server.web.auth.CustomAuthenticationProvider"/>

<bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.mz.server.web.service.CustomUserDetailsService"/>

<sec:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider"/>
</sec:authentication-manager>

<sec:global-method-security 
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    pre-post-annotations="enabled"/>

<!-- // END Spring Security -->
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
```

**web.xml**

```
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
<!-- // BEGIN Filters -->

<!-- Spring Security -->

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/**</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- // END FILTERS -->
<!-- //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I know your pain, I had a hell of a time figuring out Spring Security. Really debating whether it was worth it. But you probably need to add the SecurityContextPersistenceFilter. This will automatically add your Credentials to the SecurityContext using the HttpSession from the JSessionID typically. I have a custom authentication handler so there is some extra parts to my code that are not relevant but I think this should probably get you pointed in the right direction.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security.xsd">


<bean id="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository"
    class='org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository'>
    <property name='allowSessionCreation' value='false' />
</bean>

<bean id="securityContextPersistenceFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter">
    <constructor-arg ref="httpSessionSecurityContextRepository" />
</bean>

<bean id="filterChainProxy" class="org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <sec:filter-chain pattern="/rest/**"
                filters="securityContextPersistenceFilter" />
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>

<sec:global-method-security
    authentication-manager-ref="authenticationManager"
    secured-annotations="enabled" />
```

Comment: Can you try using @Secured. I will try using the (@)PreAuthorize to see if it works for me. From the docs hasPermission looks like it takes two arguments. (@)PreAuthorize("hasPermission(#contact, 'admin')") . https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html . You might also check hasRole. I think that will work for you too.

Comment: Got it! Your answer got me on the right track here. I also used [this tutorial](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/03/spring-security-by-example-securing.html) which showed me how to implement the permission evaluation part. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: Quick update, after getting it all working. I removed all spring due to performance overhead. I switched to using Guice for DI and Shiro for security. I found it very easy to write  custom authentication handler and enable annotation based security.

Comment: Spring Security is _not_ worth it. It's better just to write your own. At least you would know what it's doing. I'll never work on another Spring application by choice again.